# Is it a good practice to parameterize error message in exception constructor?

Tags: c++, exception, printf

I want to throw a exception with more detailed information about what input/result caused the problem. Then I can record helpful error message into log while I catch these exceptions. I am working on VS2012, which has not implemented parameter pack. So currently I use vsprintf to merge the variable length arguments into string.

1. Is it a good practice to use such `printf-like` functions at error handling stage?
2. Or it is just no need to carry such detail information in exception?

Exception

```
class VargException : std::exception
{public:
    VargException (const char* fmt, ...)
    {
        va_list vargs;
        va_start(vargs, fmt);
        char buf[260] = {};
        vsprintf_s(buf, fmt, args);
        va_end(vargs);
        msgBuilt_ = tryAssign(msg_, buf);
    }
    const char* what() const { 
        return msgBuilt_? msg_.c_str(): "Error message failed to build"; 
    }
    std::string msg_;
    bool msgBuilt_;

    // Updated: Avoid dynamic std::string throw exception
    bool tryAssign(std::string& msg, const char* buf) throw()
    {
        try{ msg = buf; return true;} 
        catch (...) { return false; }
    }
};
```

Client code

```
void func(int key, int len) {
    try {
        if(notExists(key)) { throw VargException("%d key does not exist", key); }
        if(outOfRange(len)) { throw VargException("length %d is out of range.", len); }
        HRESULT hr = processSomething();
        if(FAILED(hr)) { throw VargException("FAILED to processingSomething. hr: 0x%08X", hr); }
    } catch (VargException& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: @BaummitAugen `std::exception` actually doesn't. `logic_error` and `runtime_error` do.

Comment: Arguably `vsprintf` isn't type safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an exception creation/handling code, you should be more paranoid about exceptions.

Constructing a `std::string` can `throw.`

I would add that paranoia, and otherwise accept the design.  Look up some tokens to detect 2013 mode and issue warnings/deprecation messages.

Comment: Yeah, I never thought there creating std::string may fail. This should be careful. But if dynamic string has chance to fail, does it mean it is hard to build result message by merging variable parameters while throwing excpetion? (no matter vsprintf/std::stringstream/string::opeator+)

Comment: Does this imply we should keep any operations simple at error handling stage. Fixed string literal is looks like the most safe option.

Comment: I've edited post that is added a tryAssign function to handle std::string assignment to avoid exception thrown from std::string. This may be safer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a reasonable approach (except you missed an argument to `vsprintf_s`).

Just be sure to swap it out for a type-safe solution utilising variadic templates and I/O streams.
When you can.

Answer (score 1):

I find it's easier to use std::ostringstream instead of format strings.

For example:

```
class MessageBuilder
{
public:
    MessageBuilder() {};

    MessageBuilder(const char * context)
    {
        m_os << context << ": ";
    }

    // stream operator to build message
    template <class T>
    MessageBuilder & operator<<(const T & t)
    {
        m_os << t;
        return *this;
    }

    operator std::string() const
    {
        return m_os.str();
    }

private:
    std::ostringstream m_os;
};
```

Which can be used like this to build a message.

```
MessageBuilder() << "This is a message containing an int: " << 3;
```